# Android ant build - won't load keystore

Tags: android, apache-flex, ant, air

My ant build for a Flex air 3.0 project for android with native extensions returns this error message:

```
could not load keystore file (password may be incorrect)
```

I'm sure password, keystore file name and path are all correct. I've tried to change the keystore file location & path - project root, desktop, c:\certs - but the error message remains the same. I've tried paths with no whitespace in dir names. I've created new certs.

In build.properties my keystore is referenced like this:

```
KEYSTORE=C:\dev\projects\Certificates\AndroidCert.p12
STOREPASS=mypassword
```

The part of my build.xml that deals with the keystore looks like so:

```
    <java jar="${ADT.JAR}" dir="${APP_BUILD}" fork="true" failonerror="true">
        <arg value="-package"/>
        <arg value="-target"/>
        <arg value="apk"/>
        <arg value="-storetype"/>
        <arg value="PKCS12"/>
        <arg value="-keystore"/>
        <arg value="${KEYSTORE}"/>
        <arg value="-storepass"/>
        <arg value="${STOREPASS}"/>
        <arg value="${APK_NAME}"/>
        <arg value="${APP_XML}"/>
        <arg value="${APP_SWF}"/>
        <arg value="icons/"/>
        <arg value="-extdir"/>
        <arg value="${EXT_DIR}/"/>
    </java>
```

Any help to explain the error is very much appreciated.

Comment: You can view: http://www.petefreitag.com/item/667.cfm  - `It is important that the Certificate is not placed in your source directory`

Comment: @Alex K. Thanks for the link. The cert is not in the source directory. It's also not in a directory with restricted access privileges.

Comment: Maybe try referencing the build.properties file directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run the command manually and check the output. Also check for trailing spaces in your properties file.

Comment: Accept and +1. I created cert and ran manually and it worked. Thanks for the trailing spaces tips.